# How to delete rows with NaN in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe which is actually a excel spreadsheet:

```
    Unnamed: 0  Date    Num     Company     Link    ID
0   NaN     1990-11-15  131231  apple...    http://www.example.com/201611141492/xellia...   290834
1   NaN     1990-10-22  1231    microsoft http://www.example.com/news/arnsno...     NaN
2   NaN     2011-10-20  123     apple   http://www.example.com/ator...  209384
3   NaN     2013-10-27  123     apple...    http://example.com/sections/th-shots/2016/...   098
4   NaN     1990-10-26  123     google  http://www.example.net/business/Drugmak...  098098
5   NaN     1990-10-18  1231    google...   http://example.com/news/va-rece...  NaN
6   NaN     2011-04-26  546     amazon...   http://www.example.com/news/home/20160425...    9809
```

I would like to remove all the rows that have `NaN` in the `ID` column and reindex the "index imaginary column":

```
    Unnamed: 0  Date    Num     Company     Link    ID
0   NaN     1990-11-15  131231  apple...    http://www.example.com/201611141492/xellia...   290834
1   NaN     2011-10-20  123     apple   http://www.example.com/ator...  209384
2   NaN     2013-10-27  123     apple...    http://example.com/sections/th-shots/2016/...   098
3   NaN     1990-10-26  123     google  http://www.example.net/business/Drugmak...  098098
4   NaN     2011-04-26  546     amazon...   http://www.example.com/news/home/20160425...    9809
```

I know that this can be done as follows:

```
df = df['ID'].dropna()
```

Or

```
df[df.ID != np.nan]
```

Or

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df['ID'])]

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Or

```
df[df.ID()]
```

Or:

```
df[df.ID != '']
```

And then:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

However, It didnt removed the `NaN` in `ID`. I am getting the former dataframe.

**UPDATE**

In:

```
df['ID'].values
```

Out:

```
array([ '....A lot of text....',
       nan,
       "A lot of text...",
       "More text",
       'text from the site',
       nan,
       "text from the site"], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This will not work: `df[df.ID != np.nan]`. You need `df[df.ID.notnull()]`. The reason is that `x != np.nan` is always false, even when `x is np.nan`.

Comment: You could also try `df = df[np.isfinite(df['ID'])]`

Edit: Guess you must have edited when I wrote this, in that case I would follow @IanS advice

Comment: Is ID numerical? Perhaps you are looking for empty strings: `df[df.ID != '']`

Comment: Are you sure `df = df['ID'].dropna()` does not work? Can you print `df['ID']`?

Comment: And can you show `df['ID'].values`?

Comment: try this since its an array `df = df.ID[np.logical_not(np.isnan(df.ID))]`

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy, thanks. I got: `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: Hmm, lets try this `df['ID'] = np.array([i == i for i in df['ID']).astype(str)`

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy It added `True` where I have some text and `False` where I have `nan`

Comment: Yes sorry thats a boolean comparison, you mentioned that you changed the column to a `string` type. You could do `df['ID'] = i for i in df['ID'] if i != 'nan'`

Comment: Thanks guys! @DmitryPolonskiy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
df = df[df.ID != 'nan']
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `df.dropna(axis = 1)`.

Or, `df.dropna(axis = 0, subset = "ID")`See if it helps.

Comment: The first approach didn't worked. With the second I got: `TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'text' was passed`

Comment: So, what is the data type of the "ID" column?

Comment: actually strings!

Comment: `NaN` stands for "not a number". So change the column datatype to int / float and then try `df.dropna()`

Comment: but my other elements of the dataframe are strings, what can I do?.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can't change a column to int/float if you have strings since it will spit out something like `invalid literal base 10` @MainulIslam

Comment: @student you can change individual columns to different `dtypes` however I don't think you will be able to convert strings to `int` dtype

Comment: I changed the full column to strings. Now everything is a string, what can I do?

Comment: This is how I perceive the problem: `Link` and `ID` are two different columns. If so, then check the datatype of the `ID` column. If it does not return `int64` then convert it to `int64` with `df["ID"].astype("int64") and then drop the `NaN`. A second point that I observe is that you have a column called `Unnamed`. It means this dataframe was **exported** as an excel file from another file. Try working on the file from which this file was exported. PS. If it is not against the policy of stackoverflow, and if the problem persists, I would like to tweak with the dataframe file.

Comment: I also noted the `unmaed column`. I removed it: `df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', 1)`. I changed the datatype of `ID` now all are strings.

Comment: The `ID` column needs to be changed to `int64`