# How to delete rows in Panda DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I have a list in my pandas data frame and i want to delete all the rows that have a specific value in a columns up to the 10th row.

Something like this,

del df[df.value == 5][:10]

but it's not working

anyone know the proper syntax

thanks

Comment: Try this ```df[:10] = df[df.value != 5][:10]```

Comment: no value is a specific column in my dataset.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872090/how-to-delete-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: doesn't answer the q @nazorak

Comment: You can use df[:10] = df[df.value == 5] and then drop the rows containing NaN values. If you have other rows in your dataframe that contain NaN values you can give the above rows a unique value, and then delete them. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.