# Dropping rows in a Data Frame

Tags: python, dataframe, drop

I am trying to drop some specific rows in a `DataFrame df` where, the column `Time` is anything except `06:00:00`. I tried the following code but it dosen't seem to work. I even tried adding another column Index to my file to aid the process but still it is not working. Can you please help me. I am attaching the screenshots.

The val just contains the specific time `06:00:00`. Also, please ignore the variable `req`. Thanks a lot.

[image: partOne][image: partTwo]

Comment: I am sorry I could not add the actual code due to confidentiality issues with my peers.

Comment: Please, share your code not as an image... this way we cannot reproduce it easily. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask By the way, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872090/how-to-delete-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, by default `drop` isn't `inplace` operation. Try specifying `df.drop(j, inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
df = df.drop(df[//expresion here//].index)
```

Or even better:

```
df = df[~df.a.str.contains("06:00:00")]
```

Where `a` is the name of the column you want to search the time in

Comment: ```df = df.drop(df[df["Time"]!="06:00:00"].index)``` I tried this but it deleted all the rows.

Comment: Try the second one, it worked for me. Is the column made out of strings or datetime objects?

Comment: That coloumn is made up of datatype : ```object``` (as can be seen in the first image). Also, when I went for the second one, this error popped up : ```Can only use .str accessor with string values!```

Comment: Ok That's why I asked, if its not a string you can't use `.str`. Try using `.strftime`

Comment: Can you please suggest me what should I do now? The first method is also not working. Is there any way out?

Comment: Try this maybe: `df = df[~df.a.astype(str).contains("06:00:00")]`