# Delete the rows which has some nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete the rows which has Nan values from column 2 until last one. Here is a simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['index'] = [1, 2, 3, 4,5]
df['buy'] = [ 10, 2, 6, 7,8]
df['val1'] = [1, 2, np.nan, 8, np.nan]
df['val2'] = [10, np.nan, np.nan, 28, np.nan]
df['val3'] = [11, 32, np.nan, 18, np.nan]
```

Which gives

```
   index  buy  val1  val2  val3
0      1   10   1.0  10.0  11.0
1      2    2   2.0   NaN  32.0
2      3    6   NaN   NaN   NaN
3      4    7   8.0  28.0  18.0
4      5    8   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

And here is the output:

```
    index buy val1 val2 val3
  0     1     10     1     10     11
  1     2     2     2     np.nan     32
  2     4     7     8     28     18
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete rows with NaN in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872090/how-to-delete-rows-with-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iloc` + `isnull` + `all` to create the filter:

```
df[~df.iloc[:, 2:].isnull().all(1)]

   index  buy  val1  val2  val3
0      1   10   1.0  10.0  11.0
1      2    2   2.0   NaN  32.0
3      4    7   8.0  28.0  18.0
```

Or `notnull` + `any`:

```
df[df.iloc[:, 2:].notnull().any(1)]

   index  buy  val1  val2  val3
0      1   10   1.0  10.0  11.0
1      2    2   2.0   NaN  32.0
3      4    7   8.0  28.0  18.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
df.dropna()
```

to get

```
   index  buy  val1  val2  val3
0      1   10   1.0  10.0  11.0
1      2    2   2.0  12.0  32.0
3      4    7   8.0  28.0  18.0
```

## Edit

Given the updated question where **all** of `val1`, `val2`, and `val3` must be NaN for the row to be dropped, you can use

```
df.dropna(subset=['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], how='all')
```

Which, says only drop the row if all of these 3 values are NaN in the row. This gives

```
   index  buy  val1  val2  val3
0      1   10   1.0  10.0  11.0
1      2    2   2.0   NaN  32.0
3      4    7   8.0  28.0  18.0
```

Comment: Thanks. But, here if we have only one nan value, the row is also deleted! I've just updated the question.

Comment: @Whitecow Does my edit help?